# What's the difference between isset() and array_key_exists()?

Tags: php

How do the following two function calls compare:

```
isset($a['key'])

array_key_exists('key', $a)
```

Comment: now isset returns FALSE if the value is null or empty. array_key_exists returns true even if the array index value is empty.
previously isset returns TRUE even if the array index value is empty, so it can be used to check wether an array key exists.

Answer (score 590):

[`array_key_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-key-exists.php) will definitely tell you if a key exists in an array, whereas [`isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.isset.php) will only return `true` if the key/variable exists **and is not `null`**.

```
$a = array('key1' => 'フーバー', 'key2' => null);

isset($a['key1']);             // true
array_key_exists('key1', $a);  // true

isset($a['key2']);             // false
array_key_exists('key2', $a);  // true
```

There is another important difference: [`isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.isset.php) doesn't complain when `$a` does not exist, while [`array_key_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-key-exists.php) does.

Comment: I wish I understood chineese :)

Comment: @Zacky Japanese. And it just says 'foobar'.

Comment: I always advocate only using `isset()` because I think that NULL should always mean exactly the same as NO VALUE or NOT SET, to avoid ambiguousness.

Comment: Also note the implication to ArrayAccess implementations (including ArrayObject).  Since array_key_exists only works on arrays, as of 5.3.0, it will fail and generate a warning if used on an ArrayAccess object, even if $obj['key'] does actually exist.  isset() respects objects and arrays, so if you follow the "if it walks like a duck" mentality, using isset() lets you treat array-like variables as arrays.

Comment: If you're ever in doubt of what is better on performance side here is a benchmark test of those two functions. http://juliusbeckmann.de/blog/php-benchmark-isset-or-array_key_exists.html

Comment: ... and preffer `isset()` because is faster! See http://stackoverflow.com/a/700264/287948 or Alex link above or Patrick below, all confirm that is faster.

Comment: @jgivoni I have to disagree, null is still a value (or more like a state) and therefor should null always be treated as such. I almost never use `isset` due to the fact that one does not really know if the **index exists or not**.

Comment: @Daniel - My point is exactly that (unfortunately) in PHP null can sometimes be regarded as a 'value' and sometimes just like the absence of a value (like a function returning nothing). To mitigate this ambiguity and avoid confusion (when reading someone else's code and going "I wonder what he meant here..."), I would like to recommend the use of `isset` over `array_key_exists`, when applicable.

Comment: `null` may be a regular value, but it *means* "no value" or "none of the above". `null` is not a useful value in itself, since it can only have exactly one value: `null`. As such it can only have exactly one meaning: "nothing". So if `isset` says "you have no value here", then it *should* be practically irrelevant whether that's because there's no such variable (i.e. no value) or because the variable is `null` (i.e. no value). That's the ideal you should strive for, but the practice can certainly be more nuanced.

Comment: @Zacky My Japanese is not great, but how can it say `foobar` if character 2 and 4 are the same.

Comment: @Wilt You want me to explain how Japanese works in a 600 character comment? :) It says "fūbā", which is as close as you'll get to "foobar" in Japanese.

Comment: I stopped using isset() in cases where I explicitly want to test for the existence of a key in an array, because in that case isset() logs a missing key notice if the key isn't there.  Apparently, isset() is faster than array_key_exists(), but IMHO array_key_exists() is cleaner and more conducive to the program logic and, thus, worth the time hit, in most cases.

Also, isset() can generate a false negative in the case where the key DOES exist and points to a NULL value.

Comment: @Reverse `isset` should not log anything, that's very unusual, I'd ask for code to reproduce this. If you don't want to use it because you need to distinguish between `null` and *nonexistent*, that's perfectly legitimate.

Comment: Here is an example in PHP: http://codepad.org/iMEOiKWK

Comment: @deceze Appears you're right!  I tested and nothing in the log.  It was a decade or two ago, so maybe this was fixed?!

Comment: @jgivoni when working with databases and tables that may allow null, null is a legitimate value. `isset()` is wrong in this case, and should be altered to actually test if a variable exists. `isset()` should not be concerned about the value.

Comment: @HugoZink Null means the same in database context as in PHP: Absence of a real value. deceze's comment above (Aug. 9, '13) also explains it very well. If you're unsure whether a specific column exists in your table, by all means use ´array_key_exists´. But if you want to know the column value for a specific row, it should be irrelevant if the value is null because it was set to null or because the column does not exist. If not, your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I don't get why people seem to think one has to be better than the other.  They're different; they answer different questions.  Most of the time I use `isset` because I want to use the variable if it's available and has a value.  But, in certain cases, null is a valid value.  For instance, distinguishing between true (positive), false (negative), and null (not set).  I also use `array_key_exists` somewhat frequently to check if a key is present in a set of options, and then set a default value if not present so later code won't trigger errors for undefined keys.

Comment: I stumbled upon this because I was trying to understand why someone would write the line `if (isset($data[$name]) || array_key_exists($name, $data))` And the last comment of this answer clarifies. The line makes sure the variable `$data` exists before testing it's subvalues exist.

Comment: @danielson317 For this I'd certainly write `isset($data) && array_key_exists($name, $data)`, otherwise it's pretty pointless. Preferably you wouldn't even need `isset` at all if you initialized your variables properly.

Comment: Special thanks for mentioning that "another important difference"! By the way, I often use isset to check some "deep" props, like `isset($webhook['leads']['update'][0]['id'])` without worrying that even the `$webhooks` variable can be non-existing. Missing something like this in JavaScript (remember those `if (webhook && webhook.leads && webhook.leads.update && webhook.leads.update[0] && webhook.leads.update[0].id)` — when you have to check _each_ level in order to avoid errors).

Comment: This answer is good. I also need to share that the complexity of those function `array_key_exists` and  `isset( $array[$index] )` is O(n) but really close to O(1), though `isset()` is faster.

Answer (score 144):

Between `array_key_exists` and `isset`, though both are very fast `[O(1)]`, `isset` is significantly faster. If this check is happening many thousands of times, you'd want to use `isset`.

It should be noted that they are not identical, though -- when the array key exists but the value is `null`, `isset` will return `false` and `array_key_exists` will return `true`. If the value may be `null`, you need to use `array_key_exists`.

---

As noted in comments, if your value may be `null`, the fast choice is:

```php
isset($foo[$key]) || array_key_exists($key, $foo)
```

Comment: could not stress this enough. just spent all day figuring out why a script was taking over 300s to execute. switched to isset(), now executes in less than 3s.

Comment: @celwell, I seriously suspect you actually have another problem somewhere else if simply switching `array_key_exists` to `isset` will give you a 297 seconds speed improvement.

Comment: Your comparison of execution time scared the shit out of me, I am compelled to use array_key_exists and if your comparison is true then it means I am in deep shit when we move to production servers :(

Comment: checking `if (isset($foo[$key]) || array_key_exists($key, $foo))` should give the same results as `array_key_exists` but faster if you know that your data will have few keys pointing to `null`

Comment: Benchmark (100000 runs):

`array_key_exists()`: 205 ms
`is_set()`: 35ms
`isset() || array_key_exists()`: 48ms

Comment: `isset($foo[$key]) && $foo[$key] !== null` might be better depending on your use case

Comment: @dtbarne `isset($foo[$key])` implies `$foo[$key] !== null`, so this test makes no sense!

Comment: That's true. Honestly no clue what I was thinking when I said that.

Comment: Or simply use: `isset($foo[$key]) || array_key_exists($key, $foo)`

Comment: More benchmark info from @MarekSkiba comment is here (where it was copied from): https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php#107786

Answer (score 19):

The main difference when working on arrays is that `array_key_exists` returns `true` when the value is `null`, while `isset` will return `false` when the array value is set to `null`.

See the PHP documentation for [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset).

Comment: `isset` returns *false* and not *null*.

Comment: Corrected, though of course deceze has the more complete answer by now.

Answer (score 15):

*<sup>**Answer to an old question** as no answer here seem to address the 'warning' problem (explanation follows)</sup>*

Basically, in this case of checking if a key exists in an array, `isset`

- tells if the expression (array) is defined, and the key is set
- no warning or error if the var is not defined, not an array ...
- **but** returns *false* if the value for that key is *null*

and `array_key_exists`

- tells if a key exists in an array as the name implies
- **but** gives a warning if the array parameter is not an *array*

So how do we check if a key exists which value may be null in a variable

- that may or may not be an array
- (or similarly is a multidimensional array for which the key check happens at dim 2 and dim 1 value may not be an array for the 1<sup>st</sup> dim (etc...))

without getting a warning, without missing the existing key when its value is *null* (what were the PHP devs thinking would also be an interesting question, but certainly not relevant on SO). And of course we don't want to use `@`

```
isset($var[$key]);            // silent but misses null values
array_key_exists($key, $var); // works but warning if $var not defined/array
```

It seems `is_array` should be involved in the equation, but it gives a warning if `$var` is not defined, so that could be a solution:

```
if (isset($var[$key]) || 
    isset($var) && is_array($var) && array_key_exists($key, $var)) ...
```

which is likely to be faster if the tests are mainly on non-null values. Otherwise for an array with mostly null values

```
if (isset($var) && is_array($var) && array_key_exists($key, $var)) ...
```

will do the work.

Answer (score 11):

The PHP function [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) determines if a particular key, or numerical index, exists for an element of an array. However, if you want to determine if a *key* exists and is associated with a *value*, the PHP language construct [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) can tell you that (and that the value is not `null`). `array_key_exists()`cannot return information about the value of a key/index.

Answer (score 7):

Function `isset()` is faster, check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php#82867

Comment: True but you have to keep in mind that `isset()` will return false if the variable is set but to the value of "`null`"

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/08a2b79aa130ccb307232d1aad3aaee7f24d7515

Answer (score 4):

Complementing (as an algebraic curiosity) the  @deceze answer with the `@` operator, and indicating cases where is "better" to use `@` ... Not really better  if you need (no log and) micro-performance optimization:

- `array_key_exists`: is true if a key exists in an array;
- `isset`: is `true` if the key/variable exists **and is not `null`** [[faster than array_key_exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/700257/287948)];
- `@$array['key']`: is `true` if the key/variable exists **and is not (`null`  or '' or  0)**; [so much slower?]

```php
$a = array('k1' => 'HELLO', 'k2' => null, 'k3' => '', 'k4' => 0);

print isset($a['k1'])? "OK $a[k1].": 'NO VALUE.';            // OK
print array_key_exists('k1', $a)? "OK $a[k1].": 'NO VALUE.'; // OK
print @$a['k1']? "OK $a[k1].": 'NO VALUE.';                  // OK
// outputs OK HELLO.  OK HELLO. OK HELLO.

print isset($a['k2'])? "OK $a[k2].": 'NO VALUE.';            // NO
print array_key_exists('k2', $a)? "OK $a[k2].": 'NO VALUE.'; // OK
print @$a['k2']? "OK $a[k2].": 'NO VALUE.';                  // NO
// outputs NO VALUE.  OK .  NO VALUE.

print isset($a['k3'])? "OK $a[k3].": 'NO VALUE.';            // OK
print array_key_exists('k3', $a)? "OK $a[k3].": 'NO VALUE.'; // OK
print @$a['k3']? "OK $a[k3].": 'NO VALUE.';                  // NO
// outputs OK . OK . NO VALUE.

print isset($a['k4'])? "OK $a[k4].": 'NO VALUE.';            // OK
print array_key_exists('k4', $a)? "OK $a[k4].": 'NO VALUE.'; // OK
print @$a['k4']? "OK $a[k4].": 'NO VALUE.';                  // NO
// outputs OK 0. OK 0. NO VALUE
```

---

PS: you can change/correct/complement this text, it is a Wiki.

Comment: Note, it is **never** better to use the `@` operator.

Comment: @Bracketworks, "Never"(?) it is a strong word for Science or Programming, even for Einstein or Newton... For me it is a little performance problem only. I use it because is short to say `$x = @$_GET['x'];`, than `$x = array_key_exists('x',$_GET)? $_GET['x']: '';`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1032161/287948) in order to decide by yourself.

Comment: No, it really is "never" better to use the `@` operator, especially when dereferencing arrays. `isset()` or `array_key_exists()` communicate the intent of the code, and don't misuse an already inherently misusable operator. Obviously you don't need to convince me, but if you can provide an instance in which the `@` operator is measurably better in performance, or communicates the intent of the code more succinctly than an alternative, I'll gladly change my tone.

Comment: @Peter Krauss: what about when you use custom error handler? my logs will fill with "key does not exist". And, usually, frameworks use custom error handlers. Not to mention that your apache error log will fill if you are not in `error_reporting(0)`.

Comment: Answering @machineaddict and others: the text is a Wiki, and is for "algebraic curiosity"... Please edit it to change/correct/complement (ex. by indicating when error_log file is filled with `@` occurrences and when not).

Answer (score 0):

The two are not exactly the same. I couldn't remember the exact differences, but they are outlined very well in [What's quicker and better to determine if an array key exists in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700227/whats-quicker-and-better-to-determine-if-an-array-key-exists-in-php).

The common consensus seems to be to use isset whenever possible, because it is a language construct and therefore faster. However, the differences should be outlined above.

Comment: The speed difference between the two should be negligible.

Comment: I am not as sure in large loops. You might still be right, and I would need to benchmark, but small savings can add up in loops. For most practical uses, the difference is, like you say, negligible.