# Multiple if statements with $_GET parameters

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

So i am trying to have 2 seperate if statements in my index.php file but for some reason the if statements are not working. Basically I am using jquery to send values using $.get to the php function

index.php:

```
if (isset($_GET['year']) && isset($_GET['month']) && isset($_GET['monthStr']))
{
}

if (isset($_GET['yearPaid']) && isset($_GET['monthPaid']) && isset($_GET['personName_id']))
{
}
```

Here is the relevant js (the second if statement does not work):

```
$.get("index.php", { 'personName_id':user_id, 'monthPaid':month, 'yearPaid':year})
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log($(data).html());
        entry.animate({
            opacity: 0.2,
        }, 1000 );
    });
```

any ideas guys?

EDIT: when i mean 'not working', the second if statement is not firing the first one working fine.

EDIT: WOW! I FEEL SO STUPID! turns out the 2nd if was nested inside the first. Sorry for the waste of time guys I really appreciate your help though

EDIT: still same problem :P

EDIT: Some how it magically fixed turns ut my ajax request from jquery was messed up

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? Do they crash? Pass when they should fail? Are all the fireld being set? Is there any debugging code in your PHP?

Comment: You named the parameter `yearPaid` and then tried to access it as `year` and `yearPaid`. One of the two will be not set in php.

Comment: I would use array_key_exists in stead of isset: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210935/difference-between-isset-and-array-key-exists

Comment: @PeterVR: ya i will look into that. this is just a first run

Comment: @KevinB: would i use a global var in js for the year then?

Comment: @RohanBhangui i don't think that would affect anything.

Comment: @KevinB: the funny thing is the first one is firing and i wonder why the second one is firing. whether they are named yearPaid or year for the same value it should not make a difference right?

Comment: The first one working fine doesn't make any sense. That doesn't match what your javascript is doing.

Comment: the first if statement is fired with a different snippet of my script....the purpose of showing the first if statement is to show that there are 2 if statements there and the second is not firing

Comment: { 'personName_id':user_id, 'monthPaid':month, 'yearPaid':year}, you do  not need to put quotes -> { personName_id :user_id, monthPaid :month, yearPaid :year}

Comment: keep that in mind but that is just formatting but thanks anyways

Comment: What's the output if you do a print_r on $_GET?

Comment: when added between the ifs: Array ( [year] => 2013 [month] => 5 [monthStr] => May )       <--- I should explain the first if returns those values

Comment: Is that after doing the request with the JS code you posted?

Comment: yes the js runs $.get and then the 2nd if statement is suppose to happen and then the .done is after the request is completed, when the request completely for now it returns undefined

Comment: FWIW `isset()` can take multiple values, so you can do `isset($_GET['year'],$_GET['month'],$_GET['monthStr'])` and that is the same as `isset($_GET['year']) && isset($_GET['month']) && isset($_GET['monthStr'])`

Comment: both eed to be fired cause the info provided at both is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i emptied my cache and did hard relaod and rewrote my jquery side of the ajax request and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Your first if isn't firing becuase you are not sending anything that the if is testing for.

The second should be firing.

Comment: thats the thing the first one is firing and firing properly the second one is not firing and when i try to echo something in side nothing gets echoed

Comment: that might be a relevant add to the question... It is unclear what is occurring as a result to this "not working"

Comment: Edit made. I tried to use an elseif statement instead of if statement for the 2nd if but that did not work either