# PHP variable inheritance issue

Tags: php, arrays, variables, inheritance, null

I'm experiencing an issue with class inheritance in PHP and I'm confused in regard to the causes as well as the workarounds. Please take a look at the code below:

```
    class Vehicle {
        public $properties = array();

        public function funky($property) {
         echo json_encode($this->properties) . PHP_EOL;
         echo json_encode(isset($this->properties[$property])) . PHP_EOL;
         echo json_encode($this->properties[$property]) . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    class Car extends Vehicle {
         public $properties = array('colour' => null, 'size' => null, 'fuel' => null);
    }

    $car = new Car();
    $car->funky('colour');
```

This prints:

```
    {"colour":null,"size":null,"fuel":null}
    false
    null
```

If I try with this child class instead where the array is initialized with non-null values:

```
    class Car extends Vehicle {
        public $properties = array('colour' => 'blue', 'size' => 8, 'fuel' => 'gas');
    }
```

Then I actually get what I expect:

```
    {"colour":"blue","size":8,"fuel":"gas"}
    true
    "blue"
```

This doesn't really make sense to me. My guess is that if the child class initializes the array with null values then it doesn't really care to actually create the array elements. However, this comes in conflict with how PHP seems to work with variables. For example:

```
    $ar = array('takis' => null);
    echo json_encode(isset($ar));
```

This prints "true"!
Is there a reasonable explanation for that? What would you suggest as a workaround?

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: `isset($ar));` $ar is set why would it print anything other than true?

Comment: $ar contains one element, it does not matter that this element has null as value, this is the reason echo json_encode(isset($ar)); to print TRUE.

Comment: Instead of `echo json_encode(..) . PHP_EOL`, get used to `var_dump(..)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`isset`](http://php.net/isset) returns `true` if the variable exists **and is not `null`**, otherwise it returns `false`.
If you need to check whether the array index exists regardless of its value use [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/array_key_exists).

Also see [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/).

Comment: You can find deceze's answer here too with better explanation. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3210982/1003917