# How To Regex Search and Replace array_key_exists with isset?

Tags: php, regex, netbeans, isset, array-key-exists

Whats the best way to do a regex search and replace for all instances of `array_key_exists()` with the more efficient `isset()`? Please, no Donald Knuth quotes regarding optimizations and yes, I'm aware of the [differences between the two functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3210982/3306354).

This is what I'm currently using in my Netbeans search and replace:

- search for:

  ```
  array_key_exists\s*\(\s*'([^']*)'\s*,([^)]*)\)
  ```
- replace with:

  ```
  isset($2['$1'])
  ```

it works well , changing this:

```
array_key_exists('my_key',$my_array)
```

to

```
isset($my_array['my_key'])
```

but doesn't pick up instances like this:

```
array_key_exists($my_key,$my_array)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I could do was to run a second search and replace to cover the instances that used variables for both arguments:

`array_key_exists($my_key,$my_array)`

search and replace 2:

- search for:

  `array_key_exists\s*\(\s*(\$[^,]*)\s*,([^)]*)\)`
- replace with:

  `isset($2[$1])`

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but adding to your current regex we find both types of search criteria.

array_key_exists\s*(\s*'|$['|\S]\s*,([^)]*))

Comment: this doesn't work for me.I tried it in the netbeans engine and a few others regex testers in line.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a WIDER spectrum when upgrading the PHP version rather than JUST this upper use case:

Didn't clean it up, but it should catch every instance I could think of.

Search:

```
array_key_exists\s*\(\s*([^,]*)\s*,\s*((\(\w+\))?[a-z0-9_$'"\{\}\[\]\-\>\:]*(\(\))*[a-z0-9$_\.\{\}\'\"\[\]\-\>\:]*)\)
```

Replace:

```
isset($2[$1])
```