# PHP associative array equivilent to Python dict.get()

Tags: php, python, arrays, dictionary, language-comparisons

I've been out of the PHP world for a couple years and I've recently inherited a PHP project. Something that should be fairly easy in PHP is eluding me though. In Python I can do the following:

```
value = some_dict.get(unknown_key, default_value)
```

My first guess to do the same in PHP was:

```
$value = $some_array[$unknown_key] || $default_value;
```

But `$value` becomes a boolean because PHP doesn't support value short-circuiting. I also get a `Notice: Undefined index: the_key` but I know I can suppress that by prefixing `@`.

Is there I way to accomplish similar behavior in PHP to Python's `dict.get(key, default)`? I checked PHP's list of [array functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) but nothing stood out to me.

Comment: try `$value = $some_array[$unknown_key] ?: $default_value;`

Comment: @adamr I like your solution the best. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Note that even in Python, `some_dict.get(unknown_key, default_value)` is not the same as `some_dict.get(unknown_key) or default_value`. The first will only return `default_value` if the key `unknown_key` is not within the dictionary, whereas the latter will return `default_value` if the key is not found or if the value is falsey.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you want something along the lines of the following:

```
$value = array_key_exists($unknown_key, $some_array) ? $some_array[$unknown_key] : $default_value;
```

This checks that the key exists and returns the value, else will assign the default value that you have assigned to `$default_value`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$value = isset($some_array[$unknown_key]) ? $some_array[$unknown_key] : $default_value;
```

This way you won't need to suppress warnings

Comment: Note that this is not exactly the same as Python's `some_dict.get(unknown_key, default_value)` for the case where the key is set but the value is `null` (or `None` in Python's case). This is the difference between `isset` and `array_key_exists` http://stackoverflow.com/q/3210935/247696

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$value = $some_array[$unknown_key] ?: $default_value;
```

This is equivalent to this line of code in Python:

```
value = some_dict.get(unknown_key, default_value)
```

Note that in the edge-case that the key exists but its value is falsey, you will get the `$default_value`, which may not be what you intend.

Comment: Note that this short hand ternary operator is only available from PHP v5.3 and above.

Comment: This will also generate an `E_NOTICE`-level warning.

Comment: Sorry for the multiple edits, but I think this much clearer now.