# Unable to access nested array in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array like them i would like to access this sub category array like this

```
foreach($data as $parent_category){
        $ndata=$parent_category['subCategory'];
        foreach ($ndata as $subCategory){

 }
}
```

Where $data is my main array **print_r($data)** give this output

When i access this array i got an error **Undefined index: subCategory**

Help me please ...

> ```
> Array (
> [1] => Array
>     (
>         [name] => Indian Culture
>         [subCategory] => Array
>             (
>                 [0] => Array
>                     (
>                         [name] => Indain Culture-1
>                         [articleId] => 10
>                     )
>
>                 [1] => Array
>                     (
>                         [name] => culture -1 
>                         [articleId] => 22
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>     )
>
> [5] => Array
>     (
>         [name] => ABC CULTURE
>     )
> ```
>
> )

Comment: it this the whole array? Because only the first item in the array has subCategory, the other has just name, hence is your undefined index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As You see, here:

```
[5] => Array
(
    [name] => ABC CULTURE
)
```

Your array does not contain element with index "subCategory". So just check, that the index is present by invoking:

```
...
if (isset($parent_category['subCategory'])) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Array key 5 doesn't have a subCategory index.

The first entry in the array will be fine.

You can check if subCategory is present using the array_key_exists function.

https://www.php.net/array_key_exists

[What's the difference between isset() and array_key_exists()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210935/difference-between-isset-and-array-key-exists)

Answer (score 0):

Item with key `5` does not contain `subCategory` key. To avoid warnings, try with:

```
foreach($data as $parent_category){
    if (isset($parent_category['subCategory'])) {
        $ndata = $parent_category['subCategory'];
        foreach ($ndata as $subCategory){

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code as below, so you will not get undefined index for those cases where you didn't have subcategory.

```
foreach($data as $parent_category){
    $ndata=isset($parent_category['subCategory'])?$parent_category['subCategory']:'';
    if(!empty($ndata)){
      foreach ($ndata as $subCategory){

      }
    }
}
```