# PHP Warning: Illegal string offset and Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm getting these two php warnings

```
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'subpages'
```

and

```
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
```

The line of code is

```
foreach ($value ['subpages'] as $subfilename => $subpageTitle) {
```

and here is the full php so you can see what's going on

**Array**

```
// Menu Items
$li_1 = 'Temp Jobs';
$li_2 = 'Domestic Jobs';
$li_3 = 'HR';
$li_4 = 'Job Resume Tips';

$pages = array(

    // Temp Jobs
    'temp or temporary or seasonal or holiday or part-time or pt' => $li_1,

    // Domestic Jobs (with submenu)
    $li_2 => array('pageTitle' => $li_2, 'subpages' => array(
        'Baby-Sitter or Babysitter' => 'Babysitter',
        'Nanny' => 'Nanny',
        'Room-Attendant' => 'Room Attendant',
        'Butler or Houseman' => 'Butler',
        'Chauffeur or Chauffeuse' => 'Chauffeur',
        'Maid' => 'Maid',
        'Housekeeper or House-Keeper' => 'Housekeeper',
        'Estate-Manager' => 'Estate Manager',
        'Property-Manager' => 'Property Manager',
        'House-Manager' => 'House Manager',
        'Tutor' => 'Tutor',
        'Caregiver or Nursing-Assistant or CNA' => 'Caregiver')),

    // HR
    $li_3.' or Human-Resource or Human-Resources' => $li_3,

    // Job Resume Tips
    'job-resume-tips' => $li_4
);

foreach ($pages as $filename => $value) {

$lis = "";
$hasCurrent = false;

if (is_array ($value)) {
    $href = '#menu';
    $pageTitle = $value ['pageTitle'];
} elseif (str_replace("-"," ", $filename) == strtolower($value)) {
    $href = $dir_structure.$filename.'/';
    $pageTitle = $value;
} else {
    $href = $dir_structure.'jobs/?position='.urlencode($filename);
    $pageTitle = $value;
}

if ($value  != '') {
    foreach ($value ['subpages'] as $subfilename => $subpageTitle) {
        $lis .= '
                <li'.(($position == $subfilename) ? ' class="current"' : '').'><a href="'.$dir_structure.'jobs/?position='.urlencode($subfilename).'">'.$subpageTitle.'</a></li>';
            if ($position == $subfilename) {
                $hasCurrent = true;
            }
    } // foreach sub_menus
    echo '
        <li'.($hasCurrent || $value == $currentPage || $position == $filename ? ' class="current"' : '').'>
        <a href="'.$href.'">'.$pageTitle.'</a>';
    if($lis != '') {
        echo '
            <ul class="subMenu">';
        echo $lis;
        echo '
            </ul>';
    } // if lis
} // if sub_menus
echo '
        </li>';
} // foreach pages
```

I already read the other questions on here and know if I replace `if ($value  != '') {` with `if (is_array ($value)) {` will get rid of the error, but then the navigation menu only shows the tabs that have sub menus. How can I get rid of this php warning and at the same time make sure all of my navigation menu tabs show up? Can't figure it out.

Not all of my top navigation tabs have drop downs. In the example above, only the top tab `Domestic Jobs` has the drop downs submenu.

Comment: have you checked what is in `$value`?

Comment: The issue is that `$pages` is not a pure 2D array, many of its children are strings.

Comment: Your condition checks value is an empty string or not. You should check `is_array($value) && array_key_exists($value['subpages'])`

Comment: HarryFink I get this error `PHP Warning:  array_key_exists() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in`

Comment: @HarryFink you need to pass in the array and the key as string so - array_key_exists('subpages', $value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to achieve the desired effect;

```
if(is_array($value)) {
    foreach ($value ['subpages'] as $subfilename => $subpageTitle) {
    .....
    } // if lis
} // if sub_menus
else {
    echo '<li class="current"><a href="'.$href.'">'.$pageTitle.'</a>';
}
```

Comment: you caught the same edit I did. I placed it down below the if sub_menus, then saw your edit. Warning gone and now all menu items show up as normal.

Answer (score 1):

In the first iteration of the loop you are trying get the subpages index of a string.

You should also do a is_array check before the loop. So this could work.

```
if isset($value['subpages']) && (is_array($value['subpages'])) {
    foreach ($value ['subpages'] as $subfilename => $subpageTitle) {
```

Comment: already said in my question above about this. It is below the code. Anyway, if I use your suggestion, I still get this error `PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'subpages'`

Comment: Sorry missed out the isset, I have updated my answer

Comment: great! no warning, but still only 1 menu tab shows.

Comment: Not to sure your code looks like it should work, try var_dumping out the $lis in the loop to see what is happening.

Comment: just a dumb mistake on my part. I didn't put an else statement below the foreach to echo out the other tabs that don't have drop downs. EvilEpidemic figured that out, so accepted his answer.

Comment: but just to clarify your answer, why the two if statements? In other words, why also include the isset?

Comment: You need to check that the key exists and is an array otherwise it will throw a warning because you are trying to check an array key that doesn't exist

Comment: If that is the case, then wouldn't the `array_key_exists` be better to use? Like this `if (is_array $value['subpages'] && array_key_exists('subpages', $value))`

Comment: Same result would be given see this for more info - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210935/difference-between-isset-and-array-key-exists

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($value['subpages']) && is_array($value['subpages'])) {
  foreach ($value['subpages'] as $subfilename => $subpageTitle) 
}
```

Comment: don't get error but only 1 menu tab shows up. It is the one with the drop downs. The other 3 are missing.