# Count the occurence of a string in multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to count the occurence of a string in multidimentional array and get it.

So I found this : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-count-values.php
and an exemple in the "User Contributed Notes".

Here my code :

```
$count_values = array();
foreach ($Bigtable as $a)
{
    foreach ($a as $table)
    {
        $count_values[$table]++;             // line 32
    }
}
asort($count_values,SORT_NUMERIC );
$onet_code=end ($count_values);
```

Here my error: Notice: Undefined index: 11-1011.00 in /home/goldiman1/www/postQuestion.php on line 32

I think that the error is in the last line when I try to get the string.

What do you guys think about it?

Thank you

Goldiman

Edit: Thank you everybody for your help ! All solutions work like a charm and I understood what was the issue, it was easier to understand Kasia answer because i'm more familiar with isset()

Comment: WHich is line 32 in your code?

Comment: $count_values[$table]++;

Comment: This isn't possible if $count_value[$table] isn't an integer.

Comment: @goldiman Thought it might be - see my answer

Comment: Arrggggggg, Thank you Jordy, Any suggestion what to do with a string?

Comment: Look at Tim's answer below, you should indeed check if the value is set, if it isn't set it to 1 if it is increment it by 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$count_values[$table]++;
```

This line is trying to increment the value in `$count_values[$table]` - but you never initialize that value in the first place!

You need to change this code to create the value at 1 if it doesn't already exist, and only increment it if it does exist.

Comment: To complete: he should use isset before calling the ++ operator

Comment: @Answers_Seeker I would use array_key_exists

Comment: Right FPar, I learned something today:  [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210935/difference-between-isset-and-array-key-exists)

Answer (score 2):

If `$table` exists on the array(key) then increment the value else create new one. Try this -

```
foreach ($Bigtable as $a)
{
    foreach ($a as $table)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($table, $count_values)) {
            $count_values[$table]++;
        } else {
            $count_values[$table] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to point him in the right direction without giving him the full solution. Still, this answer is more complete than mine so +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

by default *$count_values[$table]* won't be set

```
foreach ($a as $table)
{
    if(isset($count_values[$table])){
        $count_values[$table]++;
    } else {
        $count_values[$table] =1
    }
}
```