# PHP how can make an function like this? first()->callSecond();?

Tags: php, function

I try to make an function like this below how can do that, any example?

```
$myClass->first()->callSecond();
```

Comment: This just means the result of `$myClass->first()` is an object with the method `callSecond()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to return object all the time. It's called [fluent interface](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Fluent_interface). It can be self or other object.

```
<php
class A
{
    public function first()
    {
        // Do something

        return $this;
    }
    public function callSecond()
    {
        // Do somewthing else

        return $this;
    }
}

$a = (new A())->first()->callSecond();
```

Comment: You now something for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823434/php-how-can-close-the-html-tags-from-this-array

Answer (score 1):

```
  <?php
     class OtherClass{
        public function callSecond(){
            echo 'Second Called';
        }  
     }

    class MyClass{
        public function first(){
            return new OtherClass();
        }
    }

    $myClass = new MyClass();
    $myClass->first()->callSecond();
?>
```

Comment: No problem sir, no problem

Comment: You now something for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823434/php-how-can-close-the-html-tags-from-this-array