# Undefined offset despite array_key_exists() check

Tags: php, arrays, array-key-exists

When using the code below in a function (`$floor` & `$lift` are passed in but I've added them here for demonstration) I'm getting an `Notice: Undefined offset: 20` on the last `return` statement.

The last `return` is the mean that's mean to be used in this example but why am I getting the `Notice: Undefined offset: 20`? If I'm not mistake (which I clearly am) the `array_key_exists()` function should be preventing this? I've also tried it with `isset()` with no success.

```
$floor = 20;
$lift = false;

$moving = array(
    "no_lift" => array(
        1 => 0,
        2 => 13,
        3 => 17,
        4 => 20
    ),
    "lift"    => array(
        1 => 0,
        2 => 10,
        3 => 10,
        4 => 20
    )
);

switch ( $lift ) {
    case true:
        return ( isset( $moving["lift"][ $floor ] ) ? $moving["lift"][ $floor ] : $moving["lift"][ end( $moving["lift"] ) ] );
        break;
    case false:
        return ( array_key_exists( $floor, $moving["no_lift"] ) ? $moving["no_lift"][ $floor ] : $moving["no_lift"][ end( $moving["no_lift"] ) ] );
        break;
}
```

Comment: `end( $moving["no_lift"] )` will be `20`. Which doesn't exist.

Comment: You are trying to access the array by key, but you are actually using the values!

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to use array_key_exists to search for values. You need to use array_search instead.

Comment: `array_key_exists` function is good only for associative arrays. For sequential arrays use `count` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`end` returns the last *value* from an array, so

```
$moving["lift"][ end( $moving["lift"] ) ]
```

and

```
$moving["no_lift"][ end( $moving["no_lift"] ) ]
```

will both be, in effect,

```
$moving["no_lift"][ 20 ]
```

---

If you are intending to look for something in the array and return the last item if it isn't found, you can use `in_array` if you're looking for a value

```
if ($lift) {
    return in_array($floor, $moving['lift']) ? $floor : end($moving['lift']);
} else {
    return in_array($floor, $moving['no_lift']) ? $floor : end($moving['no_lift']);
}
```

or `isset` if you're looking for a key.

```
if ($lift) {
    return isset($floor, $moving['lift']) ? $moving['lift'][$floor] : end($moving['lift']);
} else {
    return isset($floor, $moving['no_lift']) ? $moving['no_lift'][$floor] : end($moving['no_lift']);
}
```

You can use `array_key_exists` rather than `isset` if some of the values in the array may be `null`. (You can check the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210935/difference-between-isset-and-array-key-exists) for a bit more of a description about that.)

Comment: Thanks for that - clearly a misunderstanding of the documentation on my part.

Answer (score 1):

`end` does not return the last *key*, but the last *value* of an array. So the line should read:

```
return ( array_key_exists( $floor, $moving["no_lift"] ) ? $moving["no_lift"][ $floor ] : end( $moving["no_lift"] );
```

(However that still presumes that `$moving['no_lift']` is an array.)

Comment: Thanks for that - clearly a misunderstanding of the documentation on my part.