# Is array_key_exists giving a false positive?

Tags: php, arrays

Obviously I know that `array_key_exists` is not giving a false positive. I'm doing something wrong. I just wanted to grab your attention. :)

Seriously though. I am doing this as an exercise.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$error = "";
if($_POST) 
{   
    if (!array_key_exists('email',$_POST)) {
        $error .= "<p>You did not submit an e-mail address. Please try again.</p>";
    }
    if (!array_key_exists('password',$_POST)) {
        $error .= "<p>You did not submit a password. Please try again.</p>";
    }
    echo $error;

    print_r($_POST);
}
?>
```

When I don't submit either email or password, `echo $error` outputs nothing. `print_r($_POST)` outputs whatever I sent.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please change your title to appropriately reflect your question. Click baiting is just wrong. "Obviously I know that array_key_exists is not giving a false positive."

Comment: I don't know how else to phrase it.

Comment: *"What am I missing here?"* - The html for this.

Comment: `if($_POST)` is bad practice btw.

Comment: *"When I don't submit either email or password"* – you mean when you submit the keys `email` and `password`, **but without any value**, meaning an empty string?! `array_key_exists` doesn't care about the value.

Comment: Suggest you to use isset example if(isset($_POST['email']))$error .= "<p>You did not submit an e-mail address. Please try again.</p>";

Comment: @Sivaraj What does that change?

Comment: Try with [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) rather than `!array_key_exists()` you're really more interested in whether that value has data rather than whether it exists in the request.

Comment: @CD001 Note that `"0"` is "`empty`" as well; `strlen` is usually the test you're interested in.

Comment: @deceze - won't strlen throw a warning on an non-set index though (e.g. a `textarea` with no content doesn't get passed through with the request) - so perhaps both?

Comment: array_key_exists will definitely tell you if a key exists in an array, whereas isset will only return true if the key/variable exists and is not null https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210935/difference-between-isset-and-array-key-exists

Comment: @CD001 Yes, you want to precede the `strlen` with an `array_key_exists` or `isset` test.

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST['email']` and `['password']` exist but are empty you should see it with your `print_r($_POST);`

You should check the `value` instead of the `key`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use

```
empty($_POST['email'])
```

instead of `array_key_exists`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check `empty($_POST['email'])` instead of `!array_key_exists`?

Both will check if the `key` exists and also will check if they are not `NULL`.

`empty` will additionally check if it's no `empty` array, 0(as int and as string), empty string, etc.

**EDIT**

I was late

Comment: Since POST values can never be `null`, `isset` won't do anything over `array_key_exists` here.

Comment: Correct if they are from html form. Here is considered just POST data forwarding so for example also rest client requests when someone did not added form field

Comment: HTTP does not have a `null` type. It's all just strings. No HTTP POST value can ever be `null`.

Comment: Yeah you are right. You can pass NULL with json data but then it's not in $_POST variable. edit

Answer (score -1):

I would add a hidden input to your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="formSubmitted" value="1" />
```

Then you can check for the form having been submitted, rather than checking for the existence of your `$_POST` array. Also, in case both of your fields are empty when they are submitted, this provides a separate mechanism for identifying that, rather than assuming both of your fields will be valid.

```
<?php
$error = "";

if(isset($_POST['formSubmitted']) && $_POST['formSubmitted'] == 1) {    
    if (!array_key_exists('email',$_POST)) {
        $error .= "<p>You did not submit an e-mail address. Please try again.</p>";
    }

    if (!array_key_exists('password',$_POST)) {
        $error .= "<p>You did not submit a password. Please try again.</p>";
    }

    echo $error;

    print_r($_POST);
}
?>
```

I'm also assuming you (will) have some other forms of validation to ensure that the email address and password meet some basic requirements that are not shown here.