# Replacing array_key_exists() with isset() in PHP

Tags: php, isset, isnull, array-key-exists

Knowing the differences of `array_key_exists()` and `isset()` in PHP, I see a lot of advocates on the web suggesting for replacing `array_key_exists()` with `isset()`, but I am thinking is it ***safe*** to do so?

In one project, I have the value of $var submitted by users. The value can be anything, even NULL or not set at all. I want to use `!empty($var)` to check if `$var` holds a non-empty value, but I understand that using `!empty($var)` alone is dangerous since if `$var` isn't pre-defined, PHP will throw an error.

So I have `isset($var) && !empty($var)` for checking whether `$var` holds a non-empty value.

However, things get complicated when I have a value stored in an assoc array. Compare the followings, assuming array `$arr` always exists but the key `foo` may or may not exist in `$arr`.

```
// code snipplet 1
$arr = array();
echo isset($arr['foo']);

// code snipplet 2
$arr = array();
echo array_key_exists('foo', $arr) && !is_null($arr['foo']);
```

*Code snipplet 2* will always work but it seems clumsy and harder to read. As for *code snipplet 1*, I had bad experience... I wrote something like that before in the past on a development machine. It ran fine, but when I deployed the code to the production machine, it threw errors simply because key didn't exist in array. After some debugging, I found that the PHP configs were different between the development and the production machines and their PHP versions are slightly different.

So, I am thinking is it really that **safe** to just replace `array_key_exists()` with `isset()`? If not, what can be of better alternatives  of *code snipplet 2*?

Comment: Both are different thing, `array_key_exists()` uses only when you have to search the existance of any key in the `associative array` where `isset()`  checks variable is initialized or not(it can be the array key value)

Comment: ```I understand that using !empty($var) alone is dangerous since if $var isn't pre-defined, PHP will throw an error.``` - this is wrong. empty() suppresses undefined variable errors just like isset().

Comment: `array_key_exists()` is usefull if your array can have a key with a null value in valid context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In one project, I have the value of $var submitted by users.

How does that work? Users shouldn't be able to set *variables*. They should be able to, e.g., submit form values which end up in `$_POST`. I repeat, they should not be able to directly *create variables in your scope*.

If "users" here means some sort of plugin system where people write and `include` PHP code… then you may want to think about defining a more stable interface than setting variables.

> The value can be anything, even NULL…

Not if it's a value submitted through HTTP. HTTP has no concept of `null`. It's either an empty string or doesn't exist at all.

> using `!empty($var)` alone is dangerous since if `$var` isn't pre-defined, PHP will throw an error

That is wrong. `empty` *specifically* exists to test a variable against *false* without throwing an error. `empty($var)` is the same as `!$var` **without triggering an error if the variable doesn't exist.**

> So I have `isset($var) && !empty($var)` for checking whether `$var` holds a non-empty value.

See [Why check both isset() and !empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4559925/476). (Spoiler: it's redundant.)

> ```
> echo isset($arr['foo']);
> echo array_key_exists('foo', $arr) && !is_null($arr['foo']);
> ```

These both do exactly the same thing. `isset` returns `true` if the value exists and its value is not `null`. The second line returns `true` if the array key exists and its value is not `null`. Same thing.

> I had bad experience...

You'd need to be more detailed about that, since there should be no caveat to `isset` as you describe it.

See [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/) and [Difference between isset and array_key_exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3210935/476).

Comment: In the past I was working on a project expecting something crazy from user over HTTP(ajax). A simplified version of the code was like 

`$prefix = 'data_'; 
foreach ($_POST as $k=>$v) {
 ${$prefix.$k} = json_decode($v, TRUE);
}
unset($_POST);
` This is just a simplified version of it though. Using JSON, the actual code could receive something like dynamic object, arrays inside arrays, null values (with JS's undefined) etc... and it was hard to check if certain variable was set or not. Don't ask me why it was like that. I didn't invented it.

Comment: @user2526586 Yeah, the real issue there was the use of variable variables, not `isset`.