# Undefined index: level

Tags: php

I want to enter a number between 1 and 10 in my form but I have an error message: **Notice: Undefined index: level in**.
My variable `$_GET['level']` does not exist?

```
else if(isset($_GET['level']) && !is_numeric($_GET['level']))
    {
        $code_error = 2;
        $message = "The level must be numeric ! ";
    }

    else if ($_GET['level'] < 1 || $_GET['level'] > 10 )
    {
        $code_error = 3;
        $message = "The level must be between 1 and 10 ";

    }
```

In html I have this:

```
echo '<label for="level">Level : </label>';
    if(isset($_GET['level']))
    {
        echo '<input type="text" id="level" name="level" value="'.$_GET['level'].'" >';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<input type="text" id="level" name="level" >';
    }
    echo '<input type="submit" value="ok">';
```

Comment: Which line is generating the error? you use `$_GET['level']` in multiple places.

Comment: @ Mr Glass : else if ($_GET['level'] < 1 || $_GET['level'] > 10 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line...

```
else if ($_GET['level'] < 1 || $_GET['level'] > 10 )
```

like in the previous test where you check is set before checking it's numeric, you need to check it here as well...

```
else if (isset($_GET['level']) && ($_GET['level'] < 1 || $_GET['level'] > 10 ))
```

or restructure the code something like...

```
else if (isset($_GET['level'])) {
    if (!is_numeric($_GET['level']))
    {
        $code_error = 2;
        $message = "The level must be numeric ! ";
    }

    else if ($_GET['level'] < 1 || $_GET['level'] > 10 )
    {
        $code_error = 3;
        $message = "The level must be between 1 and 10 ";
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable `$level = $_GET['level'];` and use it instead of `$_GET['level']`.

Correct code is:

```html
$level = $_GET['level'];

echo '<label for="level">Level : </label>';
    if(isset($level))
    {
        echo '<input type="text" id="level" name="level" value="'.$level.'" >';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<input type="text" id="level" name="level" >';
    }
    echo '<input type="submit" value="ok">';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are calling `isset` on `$_GET['level']`, This means it tries to evaluate `$_GET['level']` to find if it is set.

For an array element, you need to use `array_key_exists('level', $_GET)` which finds out if there is an element without  trying to evaluate it.

Have a look here for some ["related discussion"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210935/difference-between-isset-and-array-key-exists)