# How to check if multiple array keys exists

Tags: php, key

I have a variety of arrays that will either contain

```
story & message
```

or just

```
story
```

How would I check to see if an array contains both story and message?  `array_key_exists()` only looks for that single key in the array.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If "story" will be there in either case, it sounds like you really just need to check for "message".

Comment: Using [`array_intersect_key()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) compare an array of the keys you want to verify with the array you are checking. If the length of the output is the same as the array of keys to check, they're all present.

Comment: Wyzard, I have other arrays that contain message, but not story, but those have other keys that an array with either story, or story and message would only contain.  Thanks

Comment: Are you confusing keys and values here?  Is the array formatted like `["story & message" => "value"]` or is it more like `["story & message"]`

Answer (score 94, accepted):

If you only have 2 keys to check (like in the original question), it's probably easy enough to just call [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) twice to check if the keys exists.

```
if (array_key_exists("story", $arr) && array_key_exists("message", $arr)) {
    // Both keys exist.
}
```

However this obviously doesn't scale up well to many keys. In that situation a custom function would help.

```
function array_keys_exists(array $keys, array $arr) {
   return !array_diff_key(array_flip($keys), $arr);
}
```

Comment: @alex the only issue is that if `$keys` contains **one element that is not in `$arr`** and another that is in it, `!array_diff_key` returns empty => `false` ([3v4l example](https://3v4l.org/svno0))...

Comment: I think this can be made more readable by using `!array_diff($keys, array_keys($array));` because there is a little less cognitive load involved in working out those `array_flip`s.

Answer (score 226):

Here is a solution that's scalable, even if you want to check for a large number of keys:

```
<?php

// The values in this arrays contains the names of the indexes (keys) 
// that should exist in the data array
$required = array('key1', 'key2', 'key3');

$data = array(
    'key1' => 10,
    'key2' => 20,
    'key3' => 30,
    'key4' => 40,
);

if (count(array_intersect_key(array_flip($required), $data)) === count($required)) {
    // All required keys exist!
}
```

Comment: Clever solution indeed but it's really slower (about 50% slower on my box) than a straightforward : 
    ```
    $ok = true;
    foreach( $required as $field ) {
 if( !array_key_exists( $field, $data ) )
  $ok = false;
    }

Comment: This should work with duplicate values in the array `return empty(array_intersect($keys, array_keys($array)));`

Comment: For those just wanting to check if **any** of the keys are present, use `> 0` instead of `=== count($required)`.

Comment: For those just wanting to check if **any** of the keys are present, you don't need to use `> 0` or `!empty(...)` -- just evaluate the returned array as truthy/falsey.  `if (array_intersect_key(array_flip($required), $data)) {`

Answer (score 36):

Surprisingly `array_keys_exist` doesn't exist?! In the interim that leaves some space to figure out a single line expression for this common task. I'm thinking of a shell script or another small program.

Note: each of the following solutions use concise `[…]` array declaration syntax available in php 5.4+

#### [array_diff](http://php.net/array_diff) + [array_keys](http://php.net/array_keys)

```
if (0 === count(array_diff(['story', 'message', '…'], array_keys($source)))) {
  // all keys found
} else {
  // not all
}
```

(hat tip to [Kim Stacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17530299/934195))

This approach is the most brief I've found. `array_diff()` returns an array of items present in argument 1 *not* present in argument2. Therefore an empty array indicates all keys were found. In php 5.5 you could simplify `0 === count(…)` to be simply `empty(…)`.

#### [array_reduce](http://php.net/array_reduce) + [unset](http://php.net/unset)

```
if (0 === count(array_reduce(array_keys($source), 
    function($in, $key){ unset($in[array_search($key, $in)]); return $in; }, 
    ['story', 'message', '…'])))
{
  // all keys found
} else {
  // not all
}
```

Harder to read, easy to change. `array_reduce()` uses a callback to iterate over an array to arrive at a value. By feeding the keys we're interested in the `$initial` value of `$in` and then removing keys found in source we can expect to end with 0 elements if all keys were found.

The construction is easy to modify since the keys we're interested in fit nicely on the bottom line.

#### [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) & [in_array](http://php.net/in_array)

```
if (2 === count(array_filter(array_keys($source), function($key) { 
        return in_array($key, ['story', 'message']); }
    )))
{
  // all keys found
} else {
  // not all
}
```

Simpler to write than the `array_reduce` solution but slightly tricker to edit. `array_filter` is also an iterative callback that allows you to create a filtered array by returning true (copy item to new array) or false (don't copy) in the callback. The gotchya is that you must change `2` to the number of items you expect.

This can be made more durable but verge's on preposterous readability:

```
$find = ['story', 'message'];
if (count($find) === count(array_filter(array_keys($source), function($key) use ($find) { return in_array($key, $find); })))
{
  // all keys found
} else {
  // not all
}
```

Comment: the difference will be negligible for small sets. if you're writing a library/framework that handles large sets of data you should probably performance test each unit to find bottlenecks rather than prematurely optimize.

Comment: I looked up https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys-exists.php and didn't find it.

Comment: I see what you were insinuating now. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php (or `key_exists()`) is all that is on offer for singular key checks.  Any approach using `in_array()` is going to be among the least efficient.  0 === count(...)` is not necessary -- the truthiness of the returned array is enough.

Answer (score 20):

One more possible solution:

```
if (!array_diff(['story', 'message'], array_keys($array))) {
    // OK: all the keys are in $array
} else {
   // FAIL: some keys are not
}
```

Answer (score 15):

It seems to me, that the easiest method by far would be this:

```
$required = array('a','b','c','d');

$values = array(
    'a' => '1',
    'b' => '2'
);

$missing = array_diff_key(array_flip($required), $values);
```

Prints:

```
Array(
    [c] => 2
    [d] => 3
)
```

This also allows to check which keys are missing exactly. This might be useful for error handling.

Answer (score 11):

The above solutions are clever, but unnecessarily slow. A simple foreach loop over a few keys is much faster.

```
function array_keys_exist($keys, $array){
    foreach($keys as $key){
        if(!array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I had to use the opposite here because of the premature return with `false` (`false` overrides `true` in this case). So, what works for my needs is `foreach ($keys as $key) { if (array_key_exists($key, $array)) { return true; }} return false;` My needs were if `any` key in an array exists in another array...

Answer (score 3):

If you have something like this:

```
$stuff = array();
$stuff[0] = array('story' => 'A story', 'message' => 'in a bottle');
$stuff[1] = array('story' => 'Foo');
```

You could simply `count()`:

```
foreach ($stuff as $value) {
  if (count($value) == 2) {
    // story and message
  } else {
    // only story
  }
}
```

This only works if you know for sure that you ONLY have these array keys, and nothing else.

Using array_key_exists() only supports checking one key at a time, so you will need to check both seperately:

```
foreach ($stuff as $value) {
  if (array_key_exists('story', $value) && array_key_exists('message', $value) {
    // story and message
  } else {
    // either one or both keys missing
  }
}
```

`array_key_exists()` returns true if the key is present in the array, but it is a real function and a lot to type. The language construct `isset()` will almost do the same, except if the tested value is NULL:

```
foreach ($stuff as $value) {
  if (isset($value['story']) && isset($value['message']) {
    // story and message
  } else {
    // either one or both keys missing
  }
}
```

Additionally isset allows to check multiple variables at once:

```
foreach ($stuff as $value) {
  if (isset($value['story'], $value['message']) {
    // story and message
  } else {
    // either one or both keys missing
  }
}
```

Now, to optimize the test for stuff that is set, you'd better use this "if":

```
foreach ($stuff as $value) {
  if (isset($value['story']) {
    if (isset($value['message']) {
      // story and message
    } else {
      // only story
    }
  } else {
    // No story - but message not checked
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
isset($arr['key1'], $arr['key2'])
```

only return true if both are not null

if is null, key is not in array

Comment: if the value of `$arr['key1']` or `$arr['key2']` is `null`, the code will, the key still exist.

Comment: I wrote a test please look at it @Xorifelse [test](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2b21e2a72776ed78ce3fde3ab43e59865859a32b) and please correct me if I'm wrong.
FYI: that time I knew only PHP 5.6.* version so I did for it only.

Comment: What is that code trying to accomplish?  Why are you not just using a `foreach` loop?

Comment: I wanted to add a prove that `isset` function works how I meant it, but now I realize that you were right, keys still remain in an array and therefore my answer is not correct, thank for feedback. Yes, I could use it `foreach`.

Answer (score 3):

I use something like this quite often

```
$wantedKeys = ['story', 'message'];
$hasWantedKeys = count(array_intersect(array_keys($source), $wantedKeys)) > 0
```

or to find the values for the wanted keys

```
$wantedValues = array_intersect_key($source, array_fill_keys($wantedKeys, 1))
```

Comment: `count(...) >0` is not necessary.  `(bool) array_intersect(array_keys($source), $wantedKeys)` is the same.  A non-empty array is truthy; an empty array is falsey.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$required=['a','b'];$data=['a'=>1,'b'=>2];
if(count(array_intersect($required,array_keys($data))>0){
    //a key or all keys in required exist in data
 }else{
    //no keys found
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this not work?

```
array_key_exists('story', $myarray) && array_key_exists('message', $myarray)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the function I wrote for myself to use within a class.

```
<?php
/**
 * Check the keys of an array against a list of values. Returns true if all values in the list
 is not in the array as a key. Returns false otherwise.
 *
 * @param $array Associative array with keys and values
 * @param $mustHaveKeys Array whose values contain the keys that MUST exist in $array
 * @param &$missingKeys Array. Pass by reference. An array of the missing keys in $array as string values.
 * @return Boolean. Return true only if all the values in $mustHaveKeys appear in $array as keys.
 */
    function checkIfKeysExist($array, $mustHaveKeys, &$missingKeys = array()) {
        // extract the keys of $array as an array
        $keys = array_keys($array);
        // ensure the keys we look for are unique
        $mustHaveKeys = array_unique($mustHaveKeys);
        // $missingKeys = $mustHaveKeys - $keys
        // we expect $missingKeys to be empty if all goes well
        $missingKeys = array_diff($mustHaveKeys, $keys);
        return empty($missingKeys);
    }


$arrayHasStoryAsKey = array('story' => 'some value', 'some other key' => 'some other value');
$arrayHasMessageAsKey = array('message' => 'some value', 'some other key' => 'some other value');
$arrayHasStoryMessageAsKey = array('story' => 'some value', 'message' => 'some value','some other key' => 'some other value');
$arrayHasNone = array('xxx' => 'some value', 'some other key' => 'some other value');

$keys = array('story', 'message');
if (checkIfKeysExist($arrayHasStoryAsKey, $keys)) { // return false
    echo "arrayHasStoryAsKey has all the keys<br />";
} else {
    echo "arrayHasStoryAsKey does NOT have all the keys<br />";
}

if (checkIfKeysExist($arrayHasMessageAsKey, $keys)) { // return false
    echo "arrayHasMessageAsKey has all the keys<br />";
} else {
    echo "arrayHasMessageAsKey does NOT have all the keys<br />";
}

if (checkIfKeysExist($arrayHasStoryMessageAsKey, $keys)) { // return false
    echo "arrayHasStoryMessageAsKey has all the keys<br />";
} else {
    echo "arrayHasStoryMessageAsKey does NOT have all the keys<br />";
}

if (checkIfKeysExist($arrayHasNone, $keys)) { // return false
    echo "arrayHasNone has all the keys<br />";
} else {
    echo "arrayHasNone does NOT have all the keys<br />";
}
```

I am assuming you need to check for multiple keys ALL EXIST in an array. If you are looking for a match of at least one key, let me know so I can provide another function.

Codepad here http://codepad.viper-7.com/AKVPCH

Comment: The solution is fine but there's a nice one-line gem buried: `if (0 === count(array_diff(['key1','key2','key3'], array_keys($lookIn)))) { // all keys exist } else { // nope }`

Comment: What you write is true. I do find my function more readable  though verbose. Of course, I could be mistaken. Thanks for commenting on my answer. I learn something new.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
function array_keys_exist($searchForKeys = array(), $inArray = array()) {
    $inArrayKeys = array_keys($inArray);
    return count(array_intersect($searchForKeys, $inArrayKeys)) == count($searchForKeys); 
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  "Hope this helps" is never necessary to type in any Stack Overflow answer.  It is implied that you "hope this helps" when you post your answer -- it never, ever needs to be typed out.

Comment: @mickmackusa Is your objection only to the -possibly redundant- use of the phrase "Hope this helps"? Or is it that the solution is missing some context to be better understood?

Comment: Both.  Your intention should always be to educate readers to the best of your ability without any extraneous text.  How does this answer work? What are its advantages/disadvantages versus other answers? Why should a reader use this instead of all other answers on the page? Why declare single-use variable `$inArrayKeys`?

Answer (score 1):

This is old and will probably get buried, but this is my attempt.

I had an issue similar to @Ryan. In some cases, I needed to only check if at least 1 key was in an array, and in some cases, all *needed* to be present.

So I wrote this function:

```
/**
 * A key check of an array of keys
 * @param array $keys_to_check An array of keys to check
 * @param array $array_to_check The array to check against
 * @param bool $strict Checks that all $keys_to_check are in $array_to_check | Default: false
 * @return bool
 */
function array_keys_exist(array $keys_to_check, array $array_to_check, $strict = false) {
    // Results to pass back //
    $results = false;

    // If all keys are expected //
    if ($strict) {
        // Strict check //

        // Keys to check count //
        $ktc = count($keys_to_check);
        // Array to check count //
        $atc = count(array_intersect($keys_to_check, array_keys($array_to_check)));

        // Compare all //
        if ($ktc === $atc) {
            $results = true;
        }
    } else {
        // Loose check - to see if some keys exist //

        // Loop through all keys to check //
        foreach ($keys_to_check as $ktc) {
            // Check if key exists in array to check //
            if (array_key_exists($ktc, $array_to_check)) {
                $results = true;
                // We found at least one, break loop //
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

This was a lot easier than having to write multiple `||` and `&&` blocks.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $colsRequired   = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "grapes"];
    $data           = ["apple"=>"some text", "orange"=>"some text"];
    $presentInBoth  = array_intersect($colsRequired,array_keys($data));

    if( count($presentInBoth) != count($colsRequired))
        echo "Missing keys  :" . join(",",array_diff($colsRequired,$presentInBoth));
    else
        echo "All Required cols are present";
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, could you please improve your answer by elaborating a bit and describing the code and tell why this code is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function check_keys_exists($keys_str = "", $arr = array()){
    $return = false;
    if($keys_str != "" and !empty($arr)){
        $keys = explode(',', $keys_str);
        if(!empty($keys)){
            foreach($keys as $key){
                $return = array_key_exists($key, $arr);
                if($return == false){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

//run demo

```
$key = 'a,b,c';
$array = array('a'=>'aaaa','b'=>'ccc','c'=>'eeeee');

var_dump( check_keys_exists($key, $array));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if it is bad idea but I use very simple foreach loop to check multiple array key.

```
// get post attachment source url
$image     = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id), 'single-post-thumbnail');
// read exif data
$tech_info = exif_read_data($image[0]);

// set require keys
$keys = array('Make', 'Model');

// run loop to add post metas foreach key
foreach ($keys as $key => $value)
{
    if (array_key_exists($value, $tech_info))
    {
        // add/update post meta
        update_post_meta($post_id, MPC_PREFIX . $value, $tech_info[$value]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myArray = array('key1' => '', 'key2' => '');
$keys = array('key1', 'key2', 'key3');
$keyExists = count(array_intersect($keys, array_keys($myArray)));
```

Will return true, because there are keys from $keys array in $myArray

Comment: `count()` does not return a boolean value, it returns an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Something as this could be used

```
//Say given this array
$array_in_use2 = ['hay' => 'come', 'message' => 'no', 'story' => 'yes'];
//This gives either true or false if story and message is there
count(array_intersect(['story', 'message'], array_keys($array_in_use2))) === 2;
```

Note the check against 2, if the values you want to search is different you can change.

This solution may not be efficient, but it works!

**Updates**

In one *fat* function:

```
 /**
 * Like php array_key_exists, this instead search if (one or more) keys exists in the array
 * @param array $needles - keys to look for in the array
 * @param array $haystack - the <b>Associative</b> array to search
 * @param bool $all - [Optional] if false then checks if some keys are found
 * @return bool true if the needles are found else false. <br>
 * Note: if hastack is multidimentional only the first layer is checked<br>,
 * the needles should <b>not be<b> an associative array else it returns false<br>
 * The array to search must be associative array too else false may be returned
 */
function array_keys_exists($needles, $haystack, $all = true)
{
    $size = count($needles);
    if($all) return count(array_intersect($needles, array_keys($haystack))) === $size;
    return !empty(array_intersect($needles, array_keys($haystack)));

}
```

So for example with this:

```
$array_in_use2 = ['hay' => 'come', 'message' => 'no', 'story' => 'yes'];
//One of them exists --> true
$one_or_more_exists = array_keys_exists(['story', 'message'], $array_in_use2, false);
//all of them exists --> true
$all_exists = array_keys_exists(['story', 'message'], $array_in_use2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a function to validate my post and it is an answer for this question too so let me post it.

to call my function I will use the 2 array like this

```
validatePost(['username', 'password', 'any other field'], $_POST))
```

then my function will look like this

```
 function validatePost($requiredFields, $post)
    {
        $validation = [];

        foreach($requiredFields as $required => $key)
        {
            if(!array_key_exists($key, $post))
            {
                $validation['required'][] = $key;
            }
        }
        
        return $validation;
    }
```

this will output this

```
"required": [
            "username",
            "password",
            "any other field"

    ]
```

so what this function does is validate and return all the missing fields of the post request.

Answer (score -1):

```
// sample data
$requiredKeys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'];
$arrayToValidate = ['key1' => 1, 'key2' => 2, 'key3' => 3];

function keysExist(array $requiredKeys, array $arrayToValidate) {
    if ($requiredKeys === array_keys($arrayToValidate)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```