# How can I check if multiple array keys exist?

Tags: php

Is there a simpler, smarter and clearer way to write this?

```
if (array_key_exists("name", $array) AND array_key_exists("age", $array) AND array_key_exists("size", $array) AND array_key_exists("gender", $array) {
    echo "Keys exist!";
}
```

Comment: Probably go for `in_array()` with `array_keys()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169588/how-to-check-if-multiple-array-keys-exists

Comment: `$keys = ['name','age','size','gender']; $existCount = count(array_intersect_key(array_flip($keys), $array)) == count($keys);`

Comment: Hmm, all the answers are even longer code than mine. I hoped there is a more simpler solution with less code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use simply [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), a language construct.

Language constructs are much more faster than functions.

```
<?php
$findKeys = array('name', 'age', 'size', 'gender');
if (! empty($findKeys) && ! empty($array)) {
    foreach ($findKeys as $findKey) {
        if (isset($array[$findKey])) {
            echo 'Keys exist!';
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

1) Create an array of 4 keys you need to find.

2) Loop over this array and use `isset()` to find out if the key (element) exists.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    'index1'=>'value1',
    'index2'=>'value2',
    'index3'=>'value3'
);

$indexesToSearch = array('index1', 'index2');

if(count(array_intersect(array_keys($array), $indexesToSearch)) == count($indexesToSearch))
{
    // ... do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use can also use this way..

```
<?php
function array_keys_exist($keys, $array){
    foreach($keys as $key){
        if(!isset($array[$key]))return false;
    }
    return true;
}
?>
```