# Check if all of several PHP array keys exist

Tags: php, arrays

I am currently using the following:

```
    $a = array('foo' => 'bar', 'bar' => 'foo');

    if(isset($a['foo']) && isset($a['bar'])){
      echo 'all exist';
    }
```

However, I will have several more array keys than `foo` and `bar` that I must check for. Is there a more efficient way to check for each required key than adding an `isset` for each required entry?

Comment: ignore that possible duplicate flag; i just realized the subtle difference.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can combine them in a single `isset()` call:

```
if (isset($a['foo'], $a['bar']) {
    echo 'all exist';
}
```

If you have an array of all the keys that are required, you can do:

```
if (count(array_diff($required_keys, array_keys($a))) == 0) {
    echo 'all exist';
}
```

Comment: Getting an error: `Can't use function return value in write context` for the line `if (empty(array_diff($required_keys, array_keys($a))) {`.

Comment: Apparently `empty()` requires its argument to be a variable, not an expression. Changed to use `count()`.

Comment: Regards `empty()`: `empty($x)` is equivalent to `! isset($x) || !$x`; an expression cannot be "unset", hence the restriction (which is/will be relaxed in PHP 5.5). So you could just say `if ( ! array_diff(...) )`, `count(...) == 0` is probably more readable when dealing with arrays.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I compared `count(array_diff(...)) ==  0` vs `array_diff(...) ==  []` and was able to repeatably shave off 0.3 seconds over 1000000 iterations with the latter. This translates into almost absolutely no performance gains. I opted for empty array equals empty array because it matches my coding style, but for anyone else curious, all comes down to preference.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array of all the entries you want to check, then iterate over all of them.

```
$entries = array("foo", "bar", "baz");
$allPassed = true;

foreach($entries as $entry)
{
    if( !isset( $a[$entry] ) )
    {
        $allPassed = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

If $allPassed = true, all are good - false means one or more failed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the cleanest is

```
if (array_diff(['foo', 'bar'], array_keys($a))) === []) {
    echo 'all exist';
}
```