# PHP, in_array and fast searches (by the end) in arrays

Tags: php, performance, search

I have a doubt about what's the better way to make a fast search in arrays (I'm talking about an specific case).

Supose that I have an array L = [A, B, C] (when I start). While the program is running, may be L will grow (but by the end), one possible case when I'll do the search is that L = [A, B, C, D, E].

The fact is that when I'm searching, the values that I want find could be only D and E. Now I'm using find_array(elem, array), but this function can't be "tweaked" to search starting at the end and decreasing the index, and I'm "afraid" that for all the searches the function in_array will examine all the elements with lower indexes before will find the value that I'm searching.

¿There is another search function wich fits better to my problem? ¿How works internally the in_array function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: On a sidenote: If you know beforehand that you'll only search for new values? Wouldn't it be possible to store those new values in a seperate array which will be smaller and therefore quicker to search in? (if kenforces answer isn't an option for you)

Comment: I'm using the get_declared_classes () function, and I have to discover if a specific class is loaded or not...

Comment: The php manual does not mention a function find_array(). So I am wondering if you want the key of the found element or if you just want to know wether the element exists.

Comment: I only want to verify if it exists... but maybe what i was doing is not the correct way. I'll try with class_exists () function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume that `in_array` is a linear search from 0 to n-1.

The fastest search will be to store the values as the keys and use `array_key_exists`.

```
$a['foo'] = true;
$a['bar'] = true;

if (array_key_exists('foo', $a)) ...
```

But if that's not an option, you can make your own for indexed arrays quite easily:

```
function in_array_i($needle, array $a, $i = 0);
{
  $c = count($a);
  for (;$i < $c; ++$i)
    if ($a[$i] == $needle) return true;
  return false;
}
```

It will start at `$i`, which you can keep track of yourself in order to skip the first elements.

Or alternatively...

```
function in_array_i($needle, array $a, $i = 0);
{
  return in_array($needle, $i ? array_slice($a, $i) : $a);
}
```

You can benchmark to see which is faster.

Comment: [`isset()` will be faster.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700227/whats-quicker-and-better-to-determine-if-an-array-key-exists-in-php)

Comment: @JordanArseno, yes `isset()` is faster than `array_key_exists()`, but it does return `false` for `null` values. (Not that it matters in this case.) That said, they are both essentially constant time, while `in_array()` is O(n) and performs noticeably worse as you reach the end of a large array. So I prefer to use `isset()` when `null` isn't an issue, but the main takeaway should be that `in_array()` is absolutely the wrong way to enforce uniqueness.

Answer (score 5):

Tweaking an extensive comparative test between

- [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)
- [array_flip](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) + [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)
- [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)
- [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

for numerical and string searches, by Kasim Kochkin posted on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/ksimka/21a6ff74b41451c430e8), I find the following results

using php 7.3.11

using array_flip once and multiple searches,

- for single to few searches, in_array and array_search are faster.
- for string searches, flip (once) + isset becomes faster above 200 searches.
- for numerical searches, flip (once) + isset becomes faster above 10 searches.

**results for String search (in seconds)**

| N (array size) | in_array | flip | isset | array_search | array_key_exists |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1,000,000 | 0.00845003 | 0.17343211 | 2.86E-6 | 0.00835395 | 5.01E-6 |
| 100,000 | 0.00854707 | 0.12469196 | 7.15E-6 | 0.00861216 | 6.2E-6 |
| 10,000 | 0.00854087 | 0.10549212 | 6.91E-6 | 0.00846505 | 4.05E-6 |

**Numerical search results (in seconds),**

| N (array size) | in_array | flip | isset | array_search | array_key_exists |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1,000,000 | 0.01197696 | 0.06217289 | 6.2E-6 | 0.01673698 | 4.05E-6 |
| 100,000 | 0.01191092 | 0.06582093 | 6.91E-6 | 0.01637983 | 4.05E-6 |
| 10,000 | 0.01375008 | 0.07185006 | 5.01E-6 | 0.01485705 | 4.05E-6 |

Comment: Your post looks very useful @Aurovrata, but currently it's very hard to read. Could you format it with maybe a table which would show the benchmark in a more readable way?

Comment: sure, I'll try to find some time to improve it

Comment: Here is a Markdown table generator @Aurovrata: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: wow, that's really handy.  I will update my answer leverage this table format

Comment: something looks off,  the time does not increase between 1 million and 10 thousand for in_array ?

Comment: did you run it on your machine?

Answer (score 2):

> How works internally the in_array function?

[Internally](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/standard/array.c?revision=309986&view=markup) the `in_array()` searches from the beginning to the end of the array. So in your case this is slow.

Depending of the nature of your data you can change the search strategy. If you only have *non-duplicate values* and all *values are either string or integer* (not `NULL`), a common trick is to [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) the array which works pretty fast and then check if there is an entry for your value as key in the array hash via `isset()`:

```
  $array = array( ... non-duplicate string and integer values ... );
  $needle = 'find me!';
  $lookup = array_flip($array);
  $found = isset($lookup[$needle]) ? $lookup[$needle] : false;
  if (false === $found) {
    echo "Not found!\n";
  } else {
    echo "Found at {$found}!\n";
  }
```

If these pre-conditions are not met, you can do that what *konforce* suggested.

If you have really much data and it's not only that you're looking at either from the beginning or end, you might want to implement one search algorithm on your own, like neither starting from the beginning nor end, but wrapping and/or starting at a random position to distribute the search time.

Additionally you can keep elements sorted while adding to the array probably which can then be searched much faster with a fitting algorithm.