# Isset vs array_key_exists

Tags: php, arrays

Where is `isset` or `array_key_exist` suitable to use ?

In my case both are working.

```
if( isset( $array['index'] ) {
   //Do something
}    


if( array_key_exists( 'index', $array ) {
   //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See: https://www.php.net/array_key_exists

> `isset()` does not return `TRUE` for array keys that correspond to a `NULL` value, while `array_key_exists()` does.

Answer (score 10):

To expand on Mantas's excellent answer, which describes the behavioural difference of the code:

- Use [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) if you want to find out if that key exists in the array, regardless of whether it contains a value or not.
- Use [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) if you want to find out if the key exists in an array ***and*** has a value in it of meaning. Note that `isset` will return false for `NULL` values.

The semantic difference described above leads to the behavioural difference described by Mantas.

The following code:

```
$aTestArray = array();

echo "Before key is created\r\n";
echo "isset:\r\n";
var_dump( isset( $aTestArray['TestKey'] ) );
echo "array_key_exists:\r\n";
var_dump( array_key_exists( 'TestKey', $aTestArray ) );
echo "\r\n";

$aTestArray['TestKey'] = NULL;
echo "Key is created, but set to NULL\r\n";
echo "isset:\r\n";
var_dump( isset( $aTestArray['TestKey'] ) );
echo "array_key_exists:\r\n";
var_dump( array_key_exists( 'TestKey', $aTestArray ) );
echo "\r\n";

$aTestArray['TestKey'] = 0;
echo "Key is created, and set to 0 (zero)\r\n";
echo "isset:\r\n";
var_dump( isset( $aTestArray['TestKey'] ) );
echo "array_key_exists:\r\n";
var_dump( array_key_exists( 'TestKey', $aTestArray ) );
echo "\r\n";
```

Outputs:

```
Before key is created
isset:
bool(false)
array_key_exists:
bool(false)

Key is created, but set to NULL
isset:
bool(false)
array_key_exists:
bool(true)

Key is created, and set to 0 (zero)
isset:
bool(true)
array_key_exists:
bool(true)
```

A side-effect is that a key that returns "false" from isset may still be included as key in a for each loop, as in

```
foreach( $array as $key => value )
```

Comment: also note that isset() is signifiantly faster than array_key_exists() see http://juliusbeckmann.de/blog/php-benchmark-isset-or-array_key_exists.html

Comment: @Patrick, http://stackoverflow.com/q/700227/632951

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion if you will definitely go deep through of using `arrays`

i suggest using [`array_key_exists()`](https://www.php.net/array_key_exists) just accompanied it with some usefull array functions

just like [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) . Also the fact that array functions are created is because of arrays and ease of use [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) would be having his best place to use as *e.g checking variable existence.* . OR else theres a lot of more functions to explore for `arrays` use out there.

But after all it would be truly depends on you what result are you trying to expect either you want an `array()` with `NULL` or not.