# Unable to parse JSON web service response with json_decode()

Tags: php, json

I'm struggling with parsing a web service response JSON in cases where the service returns an error.

Example JSON - success flow:

```
{
    "Response": [{
        "iconPath" : "/img/theme/destiny/icons/icon_psn.png",
        "membershipType": 2, 
        "membershipId": "4611686018429261138",    
        "displayName": "Spuff_Monkey"
     }],
    "ErrorCode": 1,
    "ThrottleSeconds": 0,
    "ErrorStatus": "Success",
    "Message": "Ok",
    "MessageData":{}
}
```

Example JSON - error flow:

```
{
    "ErrorCode": 7,
    "ThrottleSeconds": 0,
    "ErrorStatus": "ParameterParseFailure",
    "Message": "Unable to parse your parameters.  Please correct them, and try again.",
    "MessageData": {}
}
```

Now my PHP:

```
function hitWebservice($endpoint) {

    $curl = curl_init($endpoint);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);

    if(curl_exec($curl) === false) {
        echo "Curl error: " . curl_error($curl);
    }

    curl_close($curl);

    $array_response = json_decode($json_response, true);
    $function_response = array();

    if (!isset($array_response['Response'])) {
        $function_response = $array_response;
    } else {
        $function_response = $array_response['Response'];
    }

    return $function_response;
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is when the JSON includes the "Response" block I put that in a new array and return only that detail from the function, where "Response" isn't present I want to return the full JSON as an array.

However at present, where there is no "Response" I get an empty array.

There's something wrong with my logic and I can't get past it in my tiny mind, so it's time to reach out for help!

Comment: This should work fine as you have it. http://3v4l.org/p7QiY Please post the surrounding code -- most importantly, the `function` definition from which you return `$function_response`.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error.

Comment: Original post updated to include full function

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski With a reputation like yours you should really know better than creating answers OFF SITE where they are likely to dissapear well before the question does.

Comment: @RiggsFolly That is _not_ an answer of any kind. It is a validation that the current code worked. The entire comment is likely to disappear later.

Comment: @RiggsFolly And it was posted as a request to the OP to improve what had been posted. I'm here to improve questions. Read the edit history and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Can you confirm that the 'error flow' JSON is actually what you think it is? Perhaps the response from `$endpoint` contains an empty array (array of zero objects) for the `Response` part. That would explain your empty array. Note: I find it suspicious that `Response` is actually an array of objects in the 'success flow', instead of just an object!

Comment: @RiggsFolly How do you read the edit history?

Comment: @CodeGodie Click on the `edited 20 minutes ago` link about the editors icon and name

Comment: @MartenKoetsier - you hit the nail on the head! It's not actually an array and so when I handle it as an object it behaves as I require

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the fact that `Response` is an array of objects in the JSON, I suspect that the error-flow response may also contain a `Response`-field, but with an empty array as value (`[]`). That would explain your current result.

Therefore, do not check for the existence of `Response`. It may just be an empty array. Instead, check for the `ErrorCode`, `ErrorStatus` or `ErrorMessage` (whichever you think is most suitable). For example:

```
if ($array_response['ErrorStatus'] != "Success") {
    $function_response = $array_response;
} else {
    if (!isset($array_response['Response'])) {
        $function_response = null;
    } else {
        $function_response = $array_response['Response'];
    }
}
```

In the `Success`-case, you want to check for existence of `Response`, so that if it does not exist (but it *is* expected), you can raise some error).

Another possible solution is to count the number of responses:

```
if (!isset($array_response['Response'])) {
    $function_response = $array_response;
} else {
    if (count($array_response['Response']) > 0) {
        $function_response = $array_response['Response'];
    } else {
        $function_response = $array_response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you notice, both a good and a bad response contain an `ErrorCode`

You would be better designing your code to work from this field rather than test a field that may or may not exist.

So try this instead :-

```
$array_response = json_decode($json_response, true);

switch ( $array_response['ErrorCode'] ) {
case 1 :
    do_errorCode_1_processing($array_response)
    break;
 case 2 :
    do_errorCode_2_processing($array_response)
    break;

 // etc etc


}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll work logic like this in.

The problem turned out to be the endpoint response not being an array, once I treated it as a object everything was fine

Answer (score -1):

isset () is not the right function for checking if the key in an array is present or not.

Use array_key_exists () instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

so your code should look like this:

```
$array_response = json_decode($json_response, true);

$function_response = array();
if (array_key_exists('Response', $array_response)) {
    $function_response = $array_response['Response'];
} else {
    $function_response = $array_response;
}

return $function_response;
```

The above should do the trick.

Comment: It's not exactly that, `array_key_exists` is like `isset` but won't check whether the value is null. http://stackoverflow.com/q/20116275/3132718

Comment: If so then I can't see any error in his code, probably he is doing some mistake somewhere else. OP should post more of his code. The problem lies somewhere else.