# PHP Checking if email is already in use

Tags: php, forms, email

How do I check if the email is already in use? If in use, the user will be alerted that email is already  used, if not, it would proceed.

here in my codes, it did not work, it still registered even if i inputted the same email.

```
<?php

session_start();


$con=@mysql_connect("localhost","root","secretpassword");
$dbcheck = mysql_select_db("buybranded");

    if (!$dbcheck) {
        echo mysql_error();
    }


$new_email= $_POST['email'];
$xxx = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = $new_email");
$yyy = mysql_fetch_row($xxx);

if(!isset($yyy['email'])){

$hashed_password = hash( 'sha512', $_POST['password'] );
$type="customer";
$sql="INSERT INTO users(first_name, middle_name, last_name, gender, email, password, birth_date, home_address, postal_code, home_phone, mobile_phone, source, type)
VALUES 
('$_POST[first_name]','$_POST[middle_name]','$_POST[last_name]','$_POST[gender]','$_POST[email]','$hashed_password','$_POST[birth_date]','$_POST[home_address]','$_POST[postal_code]','$_POST[home_phone]','$_POST[mobile_phone]','$_POST[source]','$type')";
} 

else {
echo "hahaha";
}

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
  }

header('refresh: 0; url=../index.php#openModal');
$message = "You are now Registered, Please Sign In.";
echo("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>");
```

?>

I hope you guys can help, i am new with php. :) thank you!

Comment: You really shouldn't use `mysql_` functions for new projects as it's deprecated. Switch to `mysqli` or PDO instead.

Comment: And don't post passwords!

Comment: What happens when I type this in your email input `1 OR 1=1` ?

Comment: Per this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700227/whats-quicker-and-better-to-determine-if-an-array-key-exists-in-php Try using array_key_exists() instead of isset.

Comment: @Daan well nothing, since [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) only supports a single query "(multiple queries are not supported)". But that's definitely not the point

Comment: @sjagr Didn't know that but I made my point.

Comment: @sjagr: -infinity. `where email=1 or 1=1` is not "multiple queries". The classic "bobby tables" attack won't work, but you can STILL cause the query to fail at a meta level.

Comment: @MarcB He had an edit before that was an attempt at running multiple queries.

Comment: @VinceAgno I hope the password you posted was just a random string of characters. But if not, you should *really* **change your password**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has a syntax error, causing all queries to fail. You also fail to check for failure, so you're simply assuming everything will keep working:

```
$xxx = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = $new_email");
                                                          ^---------^--- no quotes
```

This will produce

```
... WHERE email = foo@exam
```

ple.com

and I highly doubt you have a `foo@example.com` column in your users table.

```
$xxx = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$new_email'") or die(mysql_error());
                                                          ^----------^--
```

Note the quotes here, and the addition of the `or die(...)`.

You then have further logic bugs. `$sql` only gets set if the first query DOESN'T return any valid data. But then you unconditionally try to execute that `$sql varaible, even if it never got set.

```
if (...) {
   $sql = "INSERT ...";
}
mysql_query($sql);
```

Since it only gets set if the email DIDN'T exist, you blindly try to execute a non-existent query, and THAT query() call then fails as well. The code should be more like:

```
if (...) {
   $sql = "INSERT..."
   mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
   die("Email created");
}
die("Email not created");
```

And on top of all this, you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and explanation, but the condition still does not work, even if i enter the same email, it still pushes through.

Comment: don't use `isset(email)`. it's better to check for `mysql_num_rows($xxx) > 0`)

Comment: Oh there. i tried echoing it so i could test it. thank you. :)