# Check if img src tag is empty or null or undefinded

Tags: javascript, html, json, null, undefined

I'm working with JSON data and process that data to insert it into the proper html-tags. Some times the JSON data doesn't contain information or isn't available at all. In the given example the src is empty or the kicker isn't there which gives results like {} or undefined or '' or null on this line:

```
document.getElementById("placeholder_" + (k)).src = jsonData[i].src;
```

I looked for a solution on the board and tried that but didn't succeed. Or I didn't understand the logic. Some examples that didn't work me:

```
document.getElementById('id2').src = json.img2 ? json.img2.link : 'defaultLink';
```

Or I consulted this link:

[JSON occasionally undefined - how do I check?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37028103/json-occasionally-undefined-how-do-i-check)

This is my code snippet and I want to check if `jsonData[i].src` has data (an url) in it. How can I do that?
In the second part the src is empty and in the third part the kicker is missing. How to check that?

```
  var jsonData = [
    {
    src: 'https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_girl.jpg',
    kicker: 'Kyiv',
    headline: 'Grief and defiance in city on first anniversary of war in Ukraine',
  },
  {
    src: '',
    kicker: 'Russia',
    headline: 'how can Ukraine win? And what is the feeling within Russia?',
  },
  {
    src: 'https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_girl.jpg',
    
    headline: 'how can Ukraine win? And what is the feeling within Russia?',
  }
  ]
  
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var k = 1;
    //loop through json data and insert into corresponding divs
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("placeholder_" + (k)).src = jsonData[i].src;
        document.getElementById("placeholder_" + (k = k + 1)).innerText = jsonData[i].kicker;
        document.getElementById("placeholder_" + (k = k + 1)).innerText = jsonData[i].headline;
        k = k + 1;
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const imgElement = document.querySelector('img');
const imgSrc = imgElement.getAttribute('src');

if (!imgSrc || imgSrc.trim() === '') {
  console.log('Image src is empty, null or undefined');
} else {
  console.log('Image src is not empty');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an assignment operator `=` instead of an equal to operator `==`/`===`. I suggest reading [JavaScript Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp).

The following should work:

```
document.getElementById('id2').thingToCheck> === "<thing-to-compare>" ? "<return-for-true>" : "<return-for-false>";
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I found a solution to check if there's information in this line

```
document.getElementById("placeholder_1").src = jsonData[i].src;
```

Especially this part: `jsonData[i].src`

```
if (typeof jsonData[i].src === "string" && String(jsonData[i].src).trim() !== "") {
        // jsonData[i].src contains a non-empty string (i.e., an URL). Just leave as it is.
        document.getElementById("placeholder_1").src = jsonData[i].src;
    } else {
        // jsonData[i].src is null, undefined, or an empty string just fill it with "".
        jsonData[i].src = "";
        document.getElementById("placeholder_1").src = jsonData[i].src;
    }
```