# Alternative to using foreach twice in this logic

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Maybe I am looking past something, early morning.

I have an array of 'prescriptions' that I get from my database and I store it in a public variable in my class. A quick example of what that array looks like after the SQL call...

```
$prescriptions = [
    0 => [
        'companyName' => 'FoorBar Inc.',
        'prescription' => 'SomePrescription',
        'cost' => '$9.98',
    ],
    1 => [
        'companyName' => 'FoorBar Inc.',
        'prescription' => 'SomeOtherPrescription',
        'cost' => '$15.98',
    ],
    2 => [
        'companyName' => 'Labs Inc.',
        'prescription' => 'SomePrescription',
        'cost' => '$12.38',
    ],
    3 => [
        'companyName' => 'Lorem Ipsum Inc.',
        'prescription' => 'SomePrescription',
        'cost' => '$100.98',
    ],
    4 => [
        'companyName' => 'Lorem Ipsum Inc.',
        'prescription' => 'SomePrescription',
        'cost' => '$53.08',
    ],
];
```

Now what I am looking to do is group these prescriptions by company but still persist all data attached to the prescription, so I have the following logic:

```
public function groupByCompany()
{
    $clinicArray = [];

    foreach ($this->prescriptions as $prescription) {
        $clinicArray[$prescription["companyName"]] = [];
    }

    foreach ($this->prescriptions as $prescription) {
        $clinicArray[$prescription["companyName"]][] = $prescription;
    }

    return $clinicArray;
}
```

This works just fine, I get my desired result. I just feel like there is a better way to do this and maybe without running a foreach loop twice. Any suggestions?

Thank You Everyone.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with putting both lines in the first loop.

Comment: `Any suggestions` .I'd start with "don't fix until it's broken". You are trying to optimize thing you are not even sure is not-optimal. Does it really makes sense in that order?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I guess part of refactoring code is "fix if it can be better even if it's not broken". Is it not so?

Comment: Sure, but first you need to know that it is bad, ineffective or faulty in that way or another. Having nested foreach does not automatically make your code such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With one `foreach` it is:

```
public function groupByCompany()
{
    $clinicArray = [];

    foreach ($this->prescriptions as $prescription) {
        $companyName = $prescription["companyName"];

        if (!isset($clinicArray[$companyName])) {
            $clinicArray[$companyName] = [];
        }

        $clinicArray[$companyName][] = $prescription;

    }

    return $clinicArray;
}
```

Comment: Using this awful foreach/endforeach syntax should be punishable... ;(

Comment: Beautiful, I knew I was just moving slow this AM, thanks! Will accept this as answer when I can ( 5 min wait ).

Comment: Great. Thank you.

Comment: @localheinz This is called `attempt to reply`. If you don't like some codestyle or function usage - write your own answer, __please__.

Comment: Not sure what your problem is, @u_mulder, I even upvoted your answer originally. If you don't like the features this platform provides, maybe find a new platform.

Comment: Okay I can understand that some `foreach/endforeach` not please you, but what is the purpose of replacing `isset`? Because you like `array_key_exists` more than `isset`?

Comment: And same to you - if you don't like an answer, maybe you write your own?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700227/whats-quicker-and-better-to-determine-if-an-array-key-exists-in-php.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to change the logic in your code to group the loops.

The most common in PHP is to check if the item of the array already exists using the [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function:

```
foreach ($this->prescriptions as $prescription) :

    if (!isset($clinicArray[$prescription["companyName"]])) {
        $clinicArray[$prescription["companyName"]] = [];
    }
    $clinicArray[$prescription["companyName"]][] = $prescription;

endforeach;
```