# Best way to check if set of nested array keys exist all at once

Tags: php

To avoid invalid array key errors I'm checking if every array key exists that I'm checking. When I'm checking whether a key is set on something nested 2 or 3 levels deep I'm resorting to this

```
$var = isset($this->getValue()[0]) && isset($this->getValue()[0]['value']) ? $this->getValue()[0]['value'] : false;
```

It works but it looks pretty clunky to me and doesn't feel right.

I've looked at posts like this [What's quicker and better to determine if an array key exists in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700227/whats-quicker-and-better-to-determine-if-an-array-key-exists-in-php) but they don't seem to apply to situations where I need to check multiple levels.

Is there a more proper way to do this?

Comment: You don't need to test each level separately. One `isset()` will test all the levels. You can also use the `??` shortcut, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op

Comment: Perhaps just something [like this](https://3v4l.org/k6mB9) ?

Answer (score 2):

Both [isset](https://php.net/isset) and [the null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) will short-cut as soon as they see an unset dimension, so can safely be used to test deep arrays like this.

So the following will all give the same result (assuming `getValue()` has no side-effects):

```
// Your example
$var = isset($this->getValue()[0]) && isset($this->getValue()[0]['value']) ? $this->getValue()[0]['value'] : false;

// Reduced to a single isset
$var = isset($this->getValue()[0]['value']) ? $this->getValue()[0]['value'] : false;

// Using null coalesce
$var = $this->getValue()[0]['value'] ?? false;
```

Comment: // Using short-hand ternary is WRONG. $var = true or false; isset($this->getValue()[0]['value']) = boolean TRUE

Comment: @YanAlex Oh, I see what you mean; it will end up forcing a `true`, rather than taking the returned value. I've removed that example, thanks.